# I want to see automatic code completion and code documentation over webstorm

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I am developing a project in node.js in webstorm. I don't see sufficient code completion like in Eclipse + Java. I also don't see any javascript documentation popping up with descriptions of the API - which makes it very hard to code. Please advise.

Being a java guy I am hoping to see functions and variables specific to objects that I am working on, and I don't see that in Webstorm. I guess its mainly because Javascript does not provide type safety like in Java. Is there a general workaround to this?

Comment: Was code completion working, and then suddenly stopped?  Is code completion not working at all (since I am not sure what "sufficient code completion" means)?  Is this a brand new installation?  Version?  Platform?  We really need more information to be able to help you.

Comment: Code completion in javascript will never work like in java because of dynamic typing. Deal with it.

Comment: Although if you look at the stuff Microsoft are doing with node.js you'd be surprised by how good code completion can be. And on top of that TypeScript makes type inference and code completion easier. However, code completion could be way  better in webstorm/intellij for node.js. It is worth using webstorm for painless running/debugging if you like the one editor mentality.

Comment: Code completion works pretty well. Documentation generally works, but only if the source has documentation.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I have added more details to the question.